# How to add confidence intervals to 3D surface?

Tags: r, plot, graph, 3d, confidence-interval

I have a matrix 40x40 from values obtained by interpolation using library `akima` to create a 3D surface.

I estimated CI 95% using monte carlo simulations from predicted values and now I want to add them for year 0 to my 3D graph.

I’m doing something wrong and I don’t understand how to plot vertical lines to represent the CIs.
My lines look like this:

[image]

And I want to have CI like on this image: [image]

Here's are my data, dropbox link because it's longer than the space allowed to post here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6iyd2r00k5jbws/data.rtf?dl=0

and my code:

```
    persp(xyz,theta = 45, phi = 25,border="grey40", ticktype = "detailed", zlim=c(0,.8))->res2

   y.bin <- rep(1,25)
    x.bin <- seq(-10,10,length.out = 25)

points (trans3d(x.bin, y.bin, z = y0, pmat = res2), col = 1, lwd=2)
lines (trans3d(x.bin, y.bin, z = LCI, pmat = res2), col = 1, lwd=2)
lines (trans3d(x.bin, y.bin, z = UCI, pmat = res2), col = 1, lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the upper and lower confidence intervals are being drawn as a single line. If you loop over the points with an interval, and then plot the line between the upper and lower values there, the plot looks closer to what you want. Note that point values in the example `y0` is not on many of the 3d intervals.

[image]

```
# data from link is imported
persp(xyz,theta = 45, phi = 25,border="grey40", ticktype = "detailed", zlim=c(0,.8))->res2

y.bin <- rep(1,25)
x.bin <- seq(-10,10,length.out = 25)

# y0 points
points (trans3d(x.bin, y.bin, z = y0, pmat = res2), col = 1, lwd=2)

# lines between upper and lower CIs for each location
for(i in 1:length(LCI)){
  lines (trans3d(rep(x.bin[i],2), rep(y.bin[i],2), z = c(LCI[i],UCI[i]), pmat = res2), col = 1, lwd=2)
}
```